# Is it possible to add a metamethod to a table in Lua from C?

Tags: lua

I have this array of strings in C that I can pass to Lua.  On the Lua side, I then call `table.insert` to add elements to it.  But then I need to get that table back again on the C side.

I know that I can expose a C function to Lua to do that.  But I do not want the programmer to have to remember to do that.

Instead, I'm wondering if there is a way to add a metamethod (like `__newindex`) to a table, so that I can "see" when elements are added to the Lua table and capture them automatically on the C side?

Comment: Are you asking how to, given a method, set it as the `__newindex` metamethod on a table, or how to write a C method to handle adding the new elements?

Comment: I think after writing this, I'm realizing that I just posed a question where I'm asking if I can add __newindex to a table, which, we can -- and I know how.  What I was really after is a way to push a string array from C to Lua and then get notified in C when someone appends a string to the table in Lua. I'm figuring that I need to use __newindex to do that.

Comment: Gosh, I wish this was built-in.  I find myself writing so much hairy C-API code for Lua because the thing is so batteries-not-included.

Comment: Do you only care about appending new elements, or updating existing ones too?

Comment: @010110110101: It's not clear if the "array of strings" is a proper Lua table or is some C data structure.

Comment: Also, it's not clear why your C code needs to instantly be told that the array has been modified. Broadly speaking, if this is indeed a proper Lua table, the user should not expect modifying it to cause random effects elsewhere in the program. It makes far more sense from an API construction perspective for the user to have to pass the table back that represents the new state of whatever this array represents.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a copy of the C array when what you really want is direct access to the original array. This array of strings should be stored only in C or only in Lua, and then made visible to the other side.

To store it in C, create a [userdata](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_newuserdata) that points to the array and has a metatable whose [__index](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4) is a C function that allows Lua to access and manipulate it. You can either store the userdata as a global or have Lua call a function that creates it.

To store it as a Lua table, simply make it a table and access it with [lua_getglobal](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_getglobal) and [lua_setglobal](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_setglobal).